# Scala mixin sets overridden variable to null

Tags: scala, mixins

I have the following situation:

```
class A {
  val text = "Test"
  //some initialization things using text. here represented by println
  println(text)
}
```

now I want to write unit tests for the class and therefore change the value of `text` for this purpose.

```
trait Test extends A {
  override val text = "Hello"
}

class B extends A with Test
```

The problem is that now if I create an instance of `B` the value of text is set to `"Hello"` as expected but all the initialization steps in `A` get a value of `null` for `text`

[See this fiddle for demo](http://scalafiddle.net/console/16105fb9cc614fc29e1bda00dab60d41)

My question is why is the variable `null` to the statements in the original `class A`? I guess having the old value seems more logical than just having no value all of a sudden.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you write `val text = ...`, the compiler generates a private final field (let's call it `_text`) and a method for accessing it. This happens in both `A` and `B`. Constructor of `B` calls `A`'s constructor first, but the `text` method it uses is `B`'s; so it accesses `B._text`, which isn't initialized yet!

As an alternative to `def` in @DennisTraub's answer, you can also use a `lazy val` to avoid recalculating the answer (`def` is better in this case, though). In my opinion, you generally shouldn't override `val`s to avoid issues like this.

Comment: Yeah I also came to realize that if there is the possibility that the value needs to be different in some cases then a `val` which I override as a _hack_ probably isn't the right way to implement it.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately I have no idea why it behaves this way, but I solved the problem at hand by using `def` instead of `val`:

```
class A {
  def text = "Test"
  println(text)
}

trait Mix extends A {
  override def text = "Hello"
}
```

Comment: This is a nice and easy workaround. I am leaving the question unanswered because your answer is definitely helpful but doesn't answer my question "why" it behaves that way. +1 thou because I am sure you have helped people dealing with this kind of problem stumbling over this thread in the future.